# Resume Embedded YouTube Video From Where Visitor Left Off?

Tags: video, youtube, embed, resume

I've embedded a 10 minute YouTube video onto my website using the standard iframe embed code from their website, but right now if somebody watches it halfway through and then leaves, the video resumes playback from the beginning. As I'm not showing controls on the player, it means they need to sit through the same portion of the video again.

Is there any code snippet I can use to have the video start from where they left off?

Thanks!
- James.

P.S. The search didn't return anything apart from one answer at [How to resume embedded YouTube video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39469284/how-to-resume-embedded-youtube-video), but this didn't work for me (it gave the player some weird behaviors).

Comment: Since you already know of [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39545864), you may draw more attention if you asked a more targeted question about the issue you're having with that approach.

Comment: @JacobBudin , I don't know if the solution I linked to is _actually_ a solution, as nobody bothered to respond to it and it didn't work for me at all. For example, the video player wouldn't load unless I hard refreshed the page, then sometimes it would autoplay fine, other times it would just show the loading graphic. It was totally unreliable to say the least. Hence why I'm looking for a better solution.